# decltype() doesn't work for class template being compiled

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have the following snippet  of code having a problem.
I think the compiler can't deduc the type because the type of the elements of `values` won't b known before compiling. Is that right?

```
vector values{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
vector<decltype(values[0])> {values};
ostream_iterator<int> printer{cout," "};
copy(ints.crbegin(),ints.crend(),printer);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `values[0]` is a `int &`. See for yourself:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(values[0]), int &>);
```

Creating a vector of references is all kinds of wrong. To fix this, just use `decltype` on the whole vector.

```
std::vector values{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
decltype(values) ints(values.cbegin(), values.cend());
```

For your example, none of this is really necessary because you're just copying a vector. So you can just do this:

```
std::vector ints = values;
// Or avoid CTAD entirely
auto ints = values;
```

Comment: I know tha this is unnecessary. i wanted to see something. thanks

Comment: `values[0]` has type `int` and value category **lvalue**, and the decltype rules are that this combination produces  `int &`   . The type of `values[0]` is not actually `int&`, expressions cannot have reference type

Comment: Maybe it would also be good to talk about `decltype(values)`,  this is also using `decltype` on an lvalue but the result is `vector<int>` and not `vector<int>&`  !  This is because `decltype(id-expression)` has different rules to `decltype(any_other_expression)` .

Comment: There's also `auto ints = values;`

Comment: @M.M I thought `values[0]` was an `int &` because `operator[]` returns a reference. I didn't know there was more to it than that.

Comment: I deleted the bad part